# Apple Configurator - Single App Mode

Tags: ios, mdm

I have successfully locked my iPad to use the Single App Mode.
I notice that I can no longer power off the device by holding the power off button - Is this by design?  Can this option be overridden?

I fail to understand why Apple would disable the power off button as part of the Single App Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

The intent of the single app mode is that you're using it for something like a store display, and you are restricting it to doing only that one function. You wouldn't want hooligans turning off your display, so it doesn't allow you to.

To my knowledge, there is no way to change how this works.